# How add ; after every element in result

Tags: sql, mysql

Well, for example I have some data like this.
[image]

Now I'm trying get this data.

**My code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM diary  
ORDER BY country ASC;
```

**What I get:**

| country |
| --- |
| Australia |
| Austria |
| France |
| Ireland |
| Japan |

**Expected output**: `Australia;Austria;France;Ireland;Japan`

How I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` statement:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country ORDER BY country SEPARATOR ';') AS countries FROM diary;
```

Comment: Since they don't want duplicates, you need to write `...GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country...`